# Oracle: Determine Partition Size

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with 200 hash partitions, I like to monitor daily size growth (rows and size in MB) for each of the partition.  For more information, another process loads / updates rows on this table on daily basis and I like to know the growth pattern.

I am not looking for overall table size script, but size of each partition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the size of your partitions with this statement:

```
SELECT partition_name, bytes/1024/1024 "MB"
FROM dba_segments
WHERE segment_name = 'MYTABLE'
AND segment_type = 'TABLE PARTITION';
```